# PhpStorm/WebStorm ESLint autofix TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, phpstorm, eslint

I´m working on a Vue3 TypeScript application.

I have activated the checkbox in PhpStorm's ESLint settings to "Run 'eslint --fix' on save" but it does not work.

After a long search for that I only found a https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/609#issuecomment-460554105 for Visual Studio Code

.eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2021,
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        sourceType: "module"
    },
    plugins: [
        '@typescript-eslint',
    ],
    env: {
        node: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        "prettier"
    ],
    rules: {
        // override/add rules settings here, such as:
        // 'vue/no-unused-vars': 'error'
    },
};
```

Hope someone can help me to get it working in PhpStorm.

Comment: Does it work if you change a file and then select **File > Save All** with the mouse (i.e. when not using keyboard shortcuts)?  Check **Settings | Keymap, Main Menu | File | Save All** - what shortcut is assigned to this action?

Comment: I always use `ctrl + S` which is the shortcut for File > Save All. It does not work.

Comment: Once more: does it work if you change a file and then select **File > Save All** with the mouse (i.e. when not using any keyboard shortcuts)?

Comment: No is the awnser (because i have to type at least some chars but the word "no" is to short)

Comment: does the **Fix ESLint problems** right-click menu action work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a Solution for this, the Problem was that the official by prettier provided eslint extension didn´t work, after isntalling `eslint-plugin-prettier` and changing my .eslintrc.js file to

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2021,
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        sourceType: "module",
    },
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
    env: {
        node: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    ],
    rules: {
        // override/add rules settings here, such as:
        // 'vue/no-unused-vars': 'error'
    },
};
```

atleast it works now.